# ssh running a command gives different results to running it locally

Tags: python, bash, ssh, zsh

I have a python script that uses Popen to create an appium server for a simulator on a mac

```
self.appium_process = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/appium", "-a", self.ip, "--nodeconfig", self.node_file_path, "--relaxed-security", "-p", str(appium_port), "-dc", default_capabilities], stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I created a bash shell script that calls the python script. When I run the script from the local box it works and the appium logs show the connection.
I need to run this remote via ssh however. So I use the following to call the script:

```
ssh 10.18.66.99 automation_fw/config/testscript.sh
```

This, however, always ends up with the log showing:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

I checked and the node app has an extra slash before its called:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin//node
$
```

I tried changing the path on the machine but no change. How can I get this to run from ssh in the same way as it can run locally on that same box

A

Comment: Extra slashes are usually fine. Presumably `/usr/local/bin/` is added to the `PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, which is not sourced when running a command through ssh. Maybe you can just add a similar line at the top of `testscript.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running a command vis SSH you are not starting what's called a `login shell` (more about that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)).

From the details you've shared, I would say it's some thing in your environment (running outside a logged-in shell), more specifically a problem with your `$PATH` variable. You might want to check `/etc/environment` or similar paths (depending on your Linux flavour) for the wrong value.